# Spreedly API: How to integrate into my MVC C# API?

Tags: spreedly

I wanna integrate **Spreedly API** into my MVC C# API. can anyone help me to do?

I just tried it in Spreedly home site. But there they are explained about js intgration. But I need to integration for my C# API.

Comment: I don't know spreedly but if it's an Http Rest API you can use the `HttpClient` class in C#

Comment: you can also see the various http client libraries [here](http://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/HttpClient) which may be easier and more features-bagged than the `HttpClient` class